How to ensure html2canvas snapshots are within x and y coordinates?
I have a simple React component for testing, it has an initial rectangle which can be move and reshaped, I also have a button on the screen which is supposed to allow me to take a snapshot of the Body within the rectangle but at the moment, the snapshot seems to be misaligned?

import React from "react";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";

function TestPlayground() {
  const defaultPosition = {
    startX: 1036,
    startY: 470,
    endX: 511,
    endY: 170,
  };

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    startX: defaultPosition.startX,
    startY: defaultPosition.startY,
    endX: defaultPosition.endX,
    endY: defaultPosition.endY,
    isDragging: false,
    isResizing: false,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
    resizeHandle: "",
  });

  const width = Math.abs(state.endX - state.startX);
  const height = Math.abs(state.endY - state.startY);
  const left = Math.min(state.startX, state.endX);
  const top = Math.min(state.startY, state.endY);

  function handleMouseDown(e) {
    const { clientX, clientY } = e;
    const resizeHandle = getResizeHandle(clientX, clientY);

    if (resizeHandle) {
      setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        isResizing: true,
        offsetX: clientX - state.endX,
        offsetY: clientY - state.endY,
        resizeHandle: resizeHandle,
      }));
    } else {
      setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        isDragging: true,
        offsetX: clientX - left,
        offsetY: clientY - top,
      }));
    }
  }

  function handleMouseUp() {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      isDragging: false,
      isResizing: false,
      resizeHandle: "",
    }));
  }

  function handleMouseMove(e) {
    const { clientX, clientY } = e;

    if (state.isDragging) {
      const newStartX = clientX - state.offsetX;
      const newStartY = clientY - state.offsetY;
      setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        startX: newStartX,
        startY: newStartY,
        endX: newStartX + width,
        endY: newStartY + height,
      }));
    } else if (state.isResizing) {
      const newEndX = clientX - state.offsetX;
      const newEndY = clientY - state.offsetY;
      setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        endX: newEndX,
        endY: newEndY,
      }));
    }
  }

  function getResizeHandle(clientX, clientY) {
    const handleSize = 10;

    const handlePositions = {
      nw: { x: left, y: top },
      ne: { x: left + width, y: top },
      sw: { x: left, y: top + height },
      se: { x: left + width, y: top + height },
    };

    for (let handle in handlePositions) {
      const { x, y } = handlePositions[handle];
      if (
        clientX >= x - handleSize &&
        clientX <= x &&
        clientY >= y - handleSize &&
        clientY <= y
      ) {
        return handle;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  const takeSnapShot = () => {
    const body = document.querySelector("body");

    if (body) {
      html2canvas(body).then((canvas) => {
        const croppedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const croppedCanvasContext = croppedCanvas.getContext("2d");

        const width = Math.abs(state.endX - state.startX);
        const height = Math.abs(state.endY - state.startY);
        const left = Math.min(state.startX, state.endX);
        const top = Math.min(state.startY, state.endY);

        croppedCanvas.width = width;
        croppedCanvas.height = height;

        if (croppedCanvasContext) {
          // Draw the cropped region onto the new canvas
          croppedCanvasContext.drawImage(
            canvas,
            top, // sx: x-axis coordinate of the top-left corner of the sub-rectangle
            left, // sy: y-axis coordinate of the top-left corner of the sub-rectangle
            width, // sWidth: width of the sub-rectangle to draw
            height, // sHeight: height of the sub-rectangle to draw
            0, // dx: x-axis coordinate in the destination canvas to place the top-left corner of the source image
            0, // dy: y-axis coordinate in the destination canvas to place the top-left corner of the source image
            width, // dWidth: width to draw the image in the destination canvas (optional, will default to sWidth)
            height // dHeight: height to draw the image in the destination canvas (optional, will default to sHeight)
          );
        }

        const imageData = croppedCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        console.log(imageData);
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: `${left}px`,
          top: `${top}px`,
          width: `${width}px`,
          height: `${height}px`,
          border: "2px dotted black",
          zIndex: "99",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", // Transparent background
          cursor: state.isDragging || state.isResizing ? "grabbing" : "grab",
          resize: "both",
          overflow: "auto",
        }}
      />
      <div>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", width: 1000 }}>
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "red",
              width: 500,
              height: 200,
              alignSelf: "end",
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => takeSnapShot()}>TAKE SNAPSNOT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestPlayground;

Is my top and left value off? am I missing something here?
Thanks for the help.
